# How to remove the end tag from a HTML string using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the end tag of a given HTML string. I get the HTML string from the document like so:

```
var front = $('<div>').append($(clean_copy).contents().remove().end()).remove().html();
```

I now want to remove the `</div>` from the below:

```
<div id="div1" style="font-size: 20px"></div>
```

I am really rusty with regex but I want to try something like this:

```
console.log("Remove End: " + front.replace('/<(/)?div([^>]*)>/g', ''));
```

The above doesn't work, how can I remove **any** tag? Also some strings may not have an end tag.

Comment: So you want to remove any (all) tags or just remove the closing div tag???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try `front.replace(/<\/div>$/)`

It replaces your div.
If you like to replace any last end tag use this `front.replace(/<\/\S+>$/)`

Comment: You made your RegExp wrong.
don't use ''
RegExp is written in //
see my example