# jQuery: Remove a closing tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to use jQuery to remove a single closing HTML-Tag?

Example:

```
  <div class="one">
    <div class="two">CONTENT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have to remove the last , that means the closing div-tag after div.one is closed.

Unfortunately I have to do this with JS/jQuery since the System I'm working with on this project can't remove it.

Comment: Is this a string or is the content on the page? If it is content, the browser will already have parsed the HTML and create a valid DOM structure. There will be no lonely closing tag anymore.

Comment: Maybe you could try to make it  worky using some RegExp like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063333/how-to-remove-the-end-tag-from-a-html-string-using-js

Comment: @FelixKling: It's content on the page. Therefore there is much more structure/dom around it and therefore this </div> closes other divs and the whole structure/dom falls apart…

Comment: Modern browsers will try and correct these types of invalid markup. That said, it is not a job for jQuery at all. Invalid HTML should be dealt with before it reaches the clients browser at all. Is this HTML sitting in some file?

Comment: @albuvee once the browser has parsed the HTML it would be very difficult to rearrange the DOM to be what you need -- why is the incorrect HTML being emitted in the first place?

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Let's say «a complicated html-structure combined with a fairly limited template-system»

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Thx. I should have thought about «why is it incorrect» in the first place. I've now worked around it with php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is not possible. There simply are not closing tags at all in the page.

The closing tags exists in the HTML code before it's parsed, once it's parsed each element is one object, not a start and end point in the markup.

The browser will have tried to fix the invalid markup, but the problem is that different browsers will have done different things. Some browsers may ignore the extra closing tag, while others may imply a starting tag to make it a complete element. You could try to rearrange the elements to have them restored to the state they would have been without the extra closing tag, but to do that you need to know what all different browsers will have done when parsing the code.

Even worse, if that code is inside another `div`, it would be that tag that ended there, and the invalid code would come after that. How that would be handled depends on what the code is outside the code that you have shown, and also there different browsers may handle the invalid code in different ways.

Comment: Thx. I should have thought about «why is it incorrect» in the first place. I've now worked around it with php.

Answer (score 0):

Clone metod:

```
$tmp = $('.one').clone( true );
$('#wrapper').empty().append($tmp)
```

Comment: You can't add a starting tag using the `prepend` method. The HTML code that you try to add is invalid. The browser might allow it, but then it would add an element, not a starting tag.