# How do I replace string with HTML DOM replace

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom, replace

My string

```
xxx
<div>
test test
</div>
</div>
<h2> Details</h2>
xxx
```

And I would like to replace the whole HTML string to be like

```
xxx
<div>
test test
</div>
<h2> Details</h2>
xxx
```

So that means without this extra "`</div>`"

I try already but doesn't work:

```
result = result.replace('</div>\n<h2> Details</h2>', '<h2> Details</h2>');
```

or with regex but then "test test" is also deleted

```
const excessDiv = /<\/div>(?:.|\n|\r)+?<h2> Details<\/h2>/;
result = result.replace(excessDiv, '</div><h2> Details</h2>');
```

Can someone please suggest me?

Comment: I hope this one will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587408/jquery-remove-a-closing-tag

Comment: Thank you but I can not use jquery :(

Comment: Please check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68128105/13789135

Answer (score 2):

Here you go;

```js
    let htmlStr = `xxx
    <div>
    test test
    </div>
    </div>
    <h2> Details</h2>
    xxx`

    let modStr = htmlStr.replace(`</div>
    <h2> Details</h2>`, "<h2> Details</h2>")

    console.log(modStr)
```

The important part is how i write the `replace` part of code.

Comment: Thank you. What about without knowing how many empty spaces is there?

Comment: Sorry i just answered as per your answer but let me try. Please wait a sec

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try to use jQuery method `.replaceWith` instead `.replace`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the lenient parsing power of the browser to make sense of your broken HTML?

```
var el=document.createElement("div")
el.innerHTML=`xxx
<div>
test test
</div>
</div>
<h2> Details</h2>
xxx`

console.log(el.innerHTML)
```

and like magic, the extra `</div>` is gone. Yay.